# Android to Playstation and other consoles

Tags: java, android, python, bluetooth, playstation

i am trying to find if it is possible to send a message over Bluetooth to consoles like playstation 3 to make it turn on or off? since it is possible to be done from controllers. I been reading around about it. but was wondering if there is any information or exapmles that could help. as all i could find was python code which i am not really a pro in.

Any information will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.xda-developers.com/android/control-your-ps3-with-blueputdroid-for-android/

It is clearly possible to send signals from your phone to your PS3.  It may require root access on your phone to "trick" your ps3 to thinking it's talking to the correct kind of device.  The default device type of your phone is likely not the correct interface for the PS3, and you will need to tweak this information.  In order to do so requires root access, or at least it use to last time I was playing around with such things, which I believe was in 4.1....

Comment: Great information! thanks soo much. i will read in that app and i will try and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you need an emulator for this. Correct me if Im wrong.